# How to compute the test coverage of gcc itself?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

I am building gcc from source code. What changes to Makefile should I make to be able to get the coverage of GCC when it compiles a source code?

Note that I want the coverage in the GCC itself.

Comment: I might be confused by your question but GCC itself isn't capable of providing you code coverage statistics for projects you compile with it. That work is being done by a third party plugin/service and probably doesn't actually require you to compile at all.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I need the coverage of GCC itself. For example, which lines in the optimizers have been executed during compilation of a c file.

Comment: Can't you simply use `-ftime-report`?

Answer (score 1):

Before building gcc from source code, use `--enable-coverage` for the configuration. i.e. `./configure --enable-coverage`.